# Get the name of a file downloaded from an url "rewrited" on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, url-rewriting, filenames

I download a pdf file from an url rewrited, so I can't get de filename from the url. How can I get it ?

My current code:

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory()
                                        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Document.pdf"];
     //url rewrited: downloadUrl = http://mySite/pdf/2020?pointer=451&Entity=4
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downloadUrl];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used `NSURLConnection`, you can use `-[NSURLResponse suggestedFilename]` to get file name. This will take into account file name sent by the server in using the content disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{


 if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
    DownloadedFileUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
           DownloadedFileUrl = [DownloadedFileUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20"  withString:@" "];
    DownloadedFileUrl = [DownloadedFileUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://localhost"  withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"DownloadedFileUrl:%@",DownloadedFileUrl);
    NSString*str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSArray *sep = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSArray *sep1=  [[sep lastObject]  componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
 FileNameStr1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sep1 objectAtIndex:0]];


NSLog(@"FileNameStr1:%@",FileNameStr1);
}}
```